@HiltViewModel annotated class should contain exactly one @Inject or @AssistedInject annotated constructor
This is my view model code.
When I run the app, I get the error "[Hilt] @HiltViewModel annotated class should contain exactly one @Inject or @AssistedInject annotated constructor."
`@HiltViewModel
class SplashViewModel @Inject constructor() : ViewModel() {
}
`
I checked it many times and found no errors in the code.

This question is similar to: @HiltViewModel annotated class should contain exactly one @Inject annotated constructor. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

This is happen when the Fragment/Activity that is using the ViewModel is missing the @AndroidEntryPoint annotation
make sure that
 @AndroidEntryPoint
 class SplashActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
 }

 // fragment

 @AndroidEntryPoint
 class SplashFragment: BaseFragment() {
 val viewModel: SampleFragmentViewModel by viewModels()
 }


I'm using compose. I had already added @AndroidEntryPoint to MainActivity before I first got this error

Tried this @HiltViewModel
class SplashViewModel : ViewModel()

This error will also occur

your imports make sure that import javax.inject.Inject

I'm not import that

add the import and  and try
